# Xamarin.ios localization for gps permission text alert

Tags: xamarin.ios, localization

I tried following this documentation for [Localization in Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/localization/) but it seems that it does not work for me for some reason.

What I did is adding a `Localizable.strings` and `infoPlist.strings` files in both folders that I have `Resources/ar.lproj` and `Resources/en.lproj`, I checked that the build action in bundleResources. But it seems that the message presented where it asks for permission is the same entered in the `info.plist` and not the one declared in the strings files.

Anyone had the same issue ?

Comment: 1. Make sure  `CFBundleLocalizations` and `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` has been added in `info.plist`.  2. The file name should be `InfoPlist.strings` not `infoPlist.strings` 3. Debug `NSLocale.CurrentLocale.LocaleIdentifier` to see if it is the locale you are selecting.

Comment: they both already exist

`<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
 <string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
 <array>
  <string>en</string>
  <string>ar</string>
 </array>`

Comment: I changed the name to `InfoPlist.strings` as you mentioned and still same issue. The debug for `NSLocale.CurrentLocale.LocaleIdentifier` shows `"en_US"`

Comment: The permission text should be in English if LocaleIdentifier  shows `en_US`, Try to change the locale in `Setting` and watch if the permission text has been changed.